# I want to define closure variables and use them later, How do I do?

Tags: swift, closures, protocols

Below, there are one protocol which has two closure variables and a functions. And there is also a class conforming to the protocol.

```
import Foundation

protocol TestProtocol: class {
    var firstClosure: () -> () { get set }
    var secondClosure: () -> () { get set }
    func testFunction()
}

extension TestProtocol {
    func testFunction() {
        _ = firstClosure
        _ = secondClosure
    }
}

class A: TestProtocol {
    var firstClosure: () -> ()
    var secondClosure: () -> ()

    var number = 0

    init() {
        print(number)
        firstClosure = {
            self.number = 1
        }()
        print(number)
        secondClosure = {
            self.number = 2
        }()
        print(number)
        testFunction()
        print(number)
    }
}

let a = A()
```

My expected result is 0, 0, 0, 2. But, when I define closure variable, the closure variable execute immediately. What should I do?

Comment: Please don't post images. Post text.

Comment: Why do you think your expected result should be 0 0 0 2? Can you please explain?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav I just want to put right value into left variable. and execute on testFunction(). So, I expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't defining closures, you're defining `Void`s due to the fact that you execute the closures right after defining them by writing `()` after the closure. The type of `firstClosure` and `secondClosure` are both `Void`, which is a typealias for `()`. If you wanted to declare a closure that takes no input arguments and returns no value (or rather returns `Void`), you need to declare it as `() -> ()`.

```
protocol TestProtocol: class {
    var firstClosure: () -> () { get set }
    var secondClosure: () -> () { get set }
    func testFunction()
}

extension TestProtocol {
    func testFunction() {
        firstClosure()
        secondClosure()
    }
}
```

You should also modify your conforming class to directly set the closure's instead of setting them in the initializer and not to call a function with side effects (`testFunction`) in the initializer, but rather call it when you actually need it after initialisation. You need to declare your closures as `lazy`, since they access `self`.

```
class A: TestProtocol {
    var number = 0
    lazy var firstClosure: () -> Void = {
        self.number = 1
    }
    lazy var secondClosure: () -> Void = {
        self.number = 2
    }
}

A().testFunction()
```

Comment: `() -> Void` (instead of `() -> ()`) is more preferable [by Apple Codestyle](https://ericasadun.com/2015/05/11/swift-vs-void/).

Comment: I modified like this.

protocol TestProtocol: class {
    var firstClosure: () -> Void { get set }
    var secondClosure: () -> Void { get set }
    func testFunction()
}
......
    init() {
        print(number)
        firstClosure = { [weak self] in
            self?.number = 1
        }
        print(number)
        secondClosure = { [weak self] in
            self?.number = 2
        }
        print(number)
        testFunction()
        print(number)
    }
}

let a = A()

But compile error occur. Why?
Variable 'self.firstClosure' used before being initialized